# Programming Extensions for SQL Management Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

Is possible create an extension for SQL Management Studio in Visual Studio 2010? Visual Studio has a project type for making extensions for Visual Studio.

Do any templates exist in visual studio for to make one? Where should I begin if I want to learn how to make one?

Thanks.

Comment: There are some open source addins on CodePlex you could look at. Specifically SQL Server Internals Viewer and the Extended Events addin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. [Here's an article to get you started](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx). Note: [I guess there are some gotchas for 2008 R2](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/sql-server-2012-extended-events-add-in-to-manage-2008r2-instances/).

Comment: And don't forget that a lot of things change in SQL Server 2012 as well, so if you're programming with forward compatibility in mind, you may as well embrace the changes required there, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can create add-ins for SSMS. Though I think you must target VS2008. SQL Server 2012 Managament Studio is based on VS2010 SP1. As a starting point look at http://ssmsaddins.codeplex.com/